# Working with a WP Starter theme

Tags: theme-development

I am building a custom theme and I am starting with a starter theme. When add my CSS, do I modify the CSS in the style.css or add my own CSS on top of what's already there? I don't want to remove something that is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit subjective, but with a starter theme I'd go ahead and overwrite the existing styles as you see fit. You can always reference the original copy if you're worried about breaking something.

By *starter theme*, I mean a theme that has a bunch of boilerplate is intended to by copied and modified/added to (_s, for example).